# Filtrar datos de una Collection de Laravel con "LIKE" y no WHERE

Tags: laravel, filtro, collection

Tengo el siguiente método en laravel que básicamente obtiene todos los parámetros que son pasados por URL, y dentro del bucle verifica que sean válidos y si es así filtra los datos de la colección con el método `where()` que viene con las **colecciones de Laravel**.

```
protected function filterData(Collection $collection, $filters)
{
    foreach (request()->query() as $query => $value) { // Bucle por los parámetros
        if (isset($query, $value) && in_array($query, $filters)) { // Validar
            $collection = $collection->where($query, $value); // Filtrar con where()

            // $collection = $collection->like($query, $value); // Método deseado
        }
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que **me gustaría que el filtro actuara como un "LIKE" en vez de "WHERE"**. Es decir, que si el filtro es `?name=Carlos`, que también me seleccione el valor `"Carlos Appelidos"`.

Comment: Pero el nombre y el apellido están en el mismo atributo o en diferentes? Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de cómo es la colección?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Sí, ya lo he solucionado gracias a tu comentario en SO Inglés, que me hizo buscar ahí también preguntas relacionadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una [solución en SO Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419670/9818526). Básicamente he reemplazado esta parte:

```
$collection = $collection->where($query, $value);
```

Por esta otra:

```
$collection = $collection->reject(function($query) use ($value) {
    return mb_strpos($query, $value) === false;
});
```

Donde se usa la función [mb_strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strpos.php) *(Que busca la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un string en otro string)* y si esta no encuentra el string, el return devuelve true y hace que el método `reject()` lo elimine de los resultados.